# How to change color of "facebook comments plugin" in wordpress?

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I have installed this plugin on my word press (http://www.delicatebonds.com/office-romance-dos-and-donts/), but the font color of comments is white. Background of this box is also white. Just because of this, comments aren't visible.

I must either change the background of this box to black or i need to change the color of comments. Someone please help me. I don't know how to make changes in this plugin........

Comment: please give more information 
which plugin you are using ?
there are much plugins named Facebook comments

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the *light* version of the plugin?
Just remove the `colorscheme="dark"` attribute from the plugin code.

Also it seems that you are using an old wordpress plugin?
Try adding the [plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) code manually to your single post file and check the result:
1-Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag (*replace with your app_id*).

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

2-Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page (*remove the href value*).

```
<fb:comments href="http://example.com" num_posts="50" width="500" colorscheme="dark"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: I tried that. Still not working. Do you suggest to use some other plugin for the same cause? Can't this plugin be customized?

Comment: have you tried to manually adding the comment plugin and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I created for this. Wrap the Facebook Comments code inside a `<div>` and add a class to it. Like this:

```
<div class="fb-background-color">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
</div>
```

Then, add the CSS background property to it:

```
.fb-background-color {
background: blue !important;
}
```

Hope to help you somehow!